# Using different resources for different layouts. Layout distinctions

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a layout-normal and layout-large. Additionally, I provide  several splash images with different resolution: 480x800 and 1280x800.

My problems are:

1. In my task it's said that I must distinguish layouts based on device resolutions(one for 480x800 and the other for 1280x800). Is there any possibility to implement it ? Taking in consideration an assumption that handsets have 480x800 resolutions and tablets - 1280x800 and higher, I could implement this scheme but I'm not sure that it's true.
2. I've created a test project where I attempted to distinguish layouts based on size, but I can't make android use 480x800 image for layout-normal and 1280x800 image for layout-large: in both cases it shows the 480x800 image. I guess, it's because of size, in case of a device, not equals resolution, in case of an image. However, I need to provide completely different looks for 480x800 and 1280x800. what are my options here ?

Thanks.

PS I'm building against Android 2.3.

Comment: Note that just because a device has a 1280x800 screen does not mean it's a tablet. In fact, there are one or two phones with 1920x1080 displays! Similarly, there are some tablets with a 800x480 resolution display. So you can't distinguish devices based solely on screen resolution.

Comment: But what if the task states that I need to distinguish design based on resolution ?

Comment: Then I'd say you should have the task clarified, since basing layouts on screen resolution alone is definitely not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have the "[Supporting Multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)" documentation that helps on that matter.

> For example, the following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Comment: It answers **none** of my questions. I mean - the topic is related, but I can't draw any decisions to my problems from it.

Comment: Table 2 on the linked page might be of some relevance if you choose to take that route.